# how to show count increment value on icon on next page after clicking from first page button

Tags: react-native, state, react-props

```
 class ContentPage extends Component {

     constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      data: '',
      count: 0 , 
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
        this.deletehandle = this.deletehandle.bind(this)

  }

      handleClick(){
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        count: prevState.count + 1
      }
    })
  }
   deletehandle(){
  if (this.state.count === 0) {
      this.setState({
        counter: 0
      });
    } else {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        count: this.state.count - 1
      }));
    }

   }
```

this is my increment and decrement code on first page and after on press handleclicked it increases and the state value i want to show is on next page on icon 
i have used

{this.state.count}

```
          </View>
          <View style={{alignItems:'flex-end',alignContent:'flex-end',marginLeft:260}}>
     <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 18}}> Quantity : </Text><Text style={{fontSize:18}}>{this.state.count}</Text>
          </View>
         </View>



<View style={{height: 4, width: 30}} />
            <TouchableOpacity
            // onPress={this._AddCart}
            onPress={this.handleClick}
              style={{
                height: 40,
                width: 130,
                backgroundColor: 'orange',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                borderRadius:8
              }}>
              <Text style={{color:"#FFFFFF",fontSize:15}} >Add to Cart{this.state.count}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

edited my code now showing my count state in the same page but i want to show my count numbers on next screen ?

Comment: Can you share the whole code? and what is your requirement, i am not able to understand.

Comment: just i want to show my count result on next page ? like add to cart for example and the cart icon increases with count numbers

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: edited my code  but now i m calling the count on the same page but i want to show my count numbers on next screen

Comment: paas the **this.state.count** as a parameter to child component and get the count value as props to your child component.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to navigate from page 1 to page 2?

Comment: can u show me in example? coz, i have used the as and even passed the count value as props !!!

Comment: i am not navigating if i want to use navigate then i can directly pass the params in props navigation!!!

Comment: @sourav can me show me how to call in child component?

Comment: Can you show us how you're doing it now?

Comment: i solved the issue using react-redux ! but how should i use in state and props ?

Answer (score 1):

This example is just focusing on how to pass the data as props from the parent to the child component. So please ignores the syntax and other issues.

```
// Parent Component
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  // Pass count to Child Component as props
  <ChildComponent count={this.state.count}/>
}


// Child Component
class ChildComponent extends Component {
  // call count in child component using props
  this.props.count  
}
```

Comment: Try to console the props and ensure that you are getting the count value.

**constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log(this.props)
}**

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your `count` property down to the component where you want to use it (exactly like @Sourav Singh has shown in his answer). I composed an increment/decrement example for you, hope you find it helpful:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-429re

Also, you might find some interesting insights in [Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) article from official React documentation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872595/how-to-fetch-nested-array-object-inside-array-object-in-react-native/59872699?noredirect=1#comment105876222_59872699 . @alaxey Kureev can u help on these